# Bad bind variable in trigger(in one env working in another it is not)

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have below item table in which I have applied trigger.

```
    Name       Null? Type          
---------- ----- ------------- 
ID               NUMBER(10)    
ENTITYNAME       VARCHAR2(100) 
SYNONYMS         VARCHAR2(100)
```

I am inserting data into dynamicentity table. structure is below.

```
Name       Null? Type         
---------- ----- ------------ 
ID               NUMBER(38)   
ENTITYNAME       VARCHAR2(45) 
SYNONYMS         VARCHAR2(45) 
OPERATION        VARCHAR2(10) 
TABLENAME        VARCHAR2(45)
```

Whenever I am doing dml in `item` table value is getting inserted into `dynamicentity` table.

Below is the trigger. It is compiling in one env but not in another env.

```
set define off;
Create or replace trigger item_trigger
before insert or update or delete on item
for each row
begin
If inserting then
Insert into dynamicentity values(:new.id,:new.entityname,:new.synonyms,'add','ItemEntity');
end if;
if deleting then
Insert into dynamicentity values(:old.id,:old.entityname,:old.synonyms,'delete','ItemEntity');
end if;
if updating then
Insert into dynamicentity values(:new.id,:new.entityname,:new.synonyms,'modify','ItemEntity');
end if;
End item_trigger;
```

I am getting below error while compiling trigger

Trigger ITEM_TRIGGER compiled

```
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
3/34      PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.ID'
3/42      PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.ENTITYNAME'
6/34      PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.ID'
6/42      PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.ENTITYNAME'
9/34      PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.ID'
9/42      PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.ENTITYNAME'
Errors: check compiler log
```

Comment: Your code [seems to compile fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5d78d905df686046c169b57fca9a32da), both in 11g and 18c.

Comment: Did you check the schema of your item table in the instance where this is not working?

Comment: Show us what exactly got to the database: select source text from user_source or dbms_metadata.get_ddl

Comment: In Oracle you dont need to indicate the NUMBER length.  Also your string lengths are inconsistent - this may not be causing the error here, but it will eventually.

Comment: Did you use the same script to create the tables in both environments?  If your create table script in one environment had double quoted field names then you would need to match case.  eg create table dynamicentity(ID number(10)) -- :new.ID and new.id will work but create table dynamicentity("ID" number(10)) -- :new.ID will work but :new.id will not. Might not be your issue but could explain why it would work in one env and not the other.

Comment: Check the item table definitions in both environments, if your trigger compiles in one but not the other then they are obvious different.  While not related to your issue let me suggest using an AFTER trigger. You are writing new data values to another table. With a BEFORE trigger there is the possibility, however slight, that a later trigger on the same table could change those value. With an AFTER trigger those values cannot be changed any further.

Comment: @Belayer thank you so much. I just realized an and have changed the same.